# How can I hide a Element with jquery?

Tags: jquery, html, hide

How can I hide my menu_img  where the seperator is? But not where there is none.
This is my Html Code:

```
<ul class="menu">
    <li class="item-56">
    <div class="menu_img"></div><a href="#">Link1</a></li>

    <li class="item-60">
    <div class="menu_img">
     </div><span class="separator"></span>
    </li>
    <li class="item-56">
    <div class="menu_img"></div><a href="#">Link2</a></li>
</ul>
```

I want to hide my menu_img class when the seperator is displayed.

Thanks =)

Comment: http://learn.jquery.com

Comment: Try searching StackOverflow with the same question title and I bet you'll see a bunch. Sadly, this question now adds up to that bunch.

Comment: And just like that, all of the rep you earned on your first question has been lost. I think you over-simplified the question, and omitted important information from the question that would have made it a much better question. For example, any existing javascript, such as the javascript that shows the separator element(since that's where the code to hide the image should go)

Comment: Sorry, i dont know that my CMS generates seperators for links. Now i have a bug in the menu, because my menu_img is shown twice.

Comment: So, what you're asking is, in all cases where there is a separator, you want to hide the image?

Comment: Yes Kevin =) Sorry for my Bad english

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use **[.hide()](http://api.jquery.com/hide/)**:

```
$('.menu_img').hide();
```

Comment: I don't get what you means. Please edit your question with more context.